# "In the rest" or "at the rest" when talking about the heart rate?

Tags: prepositions

When talking about the normal heart rate, what is the right sentence?

> 1. The normal heart rate **in** the rest is 60-100 BPM
> 2. The normal heart rate **at** the rest is 60-100 BPM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the sentence should be:

> The normal heart rate **at rest** is 60-100 BPM.

"At" is correct, and there is no "the" in front of "rest."

Here's an excerpt from [Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/fitness/expert-answers/heart-rate/faq-20057979), a medical research site,

> Generally, a lower heart rate **at rest** implies more efficient heart function and better cardiovascular fitness.